# Picture in feed posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the graph api explorer for testing and in last days picture / source fields never get worked. ?

Does anyone have the same problem?

posting results return success but you can't see any picture on the feed

Comment: what about the code you are using to post the image, let users here check it over incase that's the issue rather than the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Does the image meet the size and ratio requirements?
`The picture must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1`

Comment: piiture is png & 128x128 , currently i have no example code i use graph api explorer for trying posts i use picture fields for the picture while posting by /me/feed

as example try to send a post by feed has this image http://i.imgur.com/q5F6m.png in picture field and see what happens by yourself